# What QJson use to parse syntax of JSON?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, qjson

I checked source code of qjson library , and it seems to use some `.yy` files , what was that ?

Can such thing be used for any wanted syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.yy file contains rules to generate Lexical Analyzer code. Whose output is used subsequently by a Parser. [Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) is a well-known tool for building Lexical Analyzer code. After that you can use tools like Bison for building Parser code. So yes any syntax which is [Context Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) can be parsed using above tools.